# Ember checkboxes are connected

Tags: ember.js, checkbox, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a table of data. You can checkmark the rows you want to save. The problem I have is that all the checkboxes are connected. So if you check one, it checks them all and if you uncheck one then they all uncheck. Some of them come pre-checked and I'm passing in the isChecked value to indicate that. How do I make each one unique?

Template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center"><br>Select<br> {{input type="checkbox" checked=allChecked}}</th>
            <th class="center">
                <a href="#" {{action 'sortBy' 'itemId'}} {{bind-attr class="itemId:active sortAscending:asc:desc"}}>ID</a>
            </th>
            <th class="">
                <a href="#" {{action 'sortBy' 'description'}} {{bind-attr class="description:active sortAscending:asc:desc"}}>Item Description</a>
            </th>
            <th>{{!-- actions --}}</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

{{#each item in pagedContent}}
        <tr>
            <td class="center">{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked name=item.itemId}}</td>
            <td class="center">{{item.itemId}}</td>
            <td class="">{{item.description}}</td>
        </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import pageableTable from 'web-app-admin/mixins/pageable-table';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(pageableTable, {
  isChecked: true,
  allChecked: true,
  allCheckedToggle: function(){
      if(this.get('allChecked') === false){
        this.set('isChecked', false);
      }
      else{
        this.set('isChecked', true);
      }
  }.observes('allChecked')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template:

```
{{#each pagedContent key='itemId' as |item|}}
        <tr>
            <td class="center">{{input type="checkbox" checked=item.isChecked name=item.itemId}}</td>
            <td class="center">{{item.itemId}}</td>
            <td class="">{{item.description}}</td>
        </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import pageableTable from 'web-app-admin/mixins/pageable-table';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(pageableTable, {
  allChecked: true,
  allCheckedToggle: Ember.observer('allChecked', function() {
    this.get('pagedContent').forEach(function (item) {
      item.set('isChecked', this.get('allChecked'));
    });
  })
});
```

And add property to item Model or object:

```
isChecked: true
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: excellent, thank you! I added "isChecked: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: true})" to the model, change checked=item.isChecked to the input, and change .set to "this.setEach('isChecked', false);" in the controller. Voila! you rock!

Comment: Ember.ArrayController is deprecated as of Ember 1.13 and removed in 2.0